# formatting an htmlString in webView

Tags: html, iphone, ios

i have an string in this format, which i fetched from an RSS feed

```
    http://puthiyathalaimurai.tv/the-train-exhibition-in-chennai
    <br/>சென்னையில், சுற்றுச்சூழலை பாதுகாக்க வேண்டியதன் அவசியம் குறித்த ரெயில் கண்காட்சியை ஏராளமான மாணவ- மாணவிகள் பார்வையிட்டு வருகின்றனர்.
```

I need to format the htmlString and display only the "description" or excluding the URL, is there any methods available to format ? any suggestions?

The code i used for formatting

```
     NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head>Description:          </head><body>%@</body></html>", _theString];  
     [_webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: Are you looking for a good beginner HTML/CSS tutorial?

Comment: no , i just need help with formatting . I need to display only the description leaving the URL.